# I want to make multiple plots using ggplot2 inside a for loop but it doesn't recognize the Y variable in the aes()

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a data frame called TumorData where the columns are gene expression data of different genes and the rows are the different patients.
I want a scatter plot of one of the columns (which has the name TP53) against each of the genes in columns 3 to 12.
I did the following

```
for(i in 3:12) {
  GeneName <- colnames(TumorData[, i])
  FileName <- paste0(GeneName, ".png")
  ggplot(TumorData, aes(x = TP53, y = GeneName)) +
    geom_point()
  ggsave(FileName)
}
```

but when I go to the saved files it's as if it were a unidimensional plot: only the first argument (TP53) was plotted accordingly. Everything is on the same horizontal line and the Y axis doesn't even have a numeric scale. The loop did read the "GeneName" because the actual gene name appears in the Y axis in each graph, but it's like it doesn't "understand" that it's the name of a column in the data frame and that it should retrieve numeric values from there.
I attached an image of how one of the graphs looks because I'm not sure I'm explaning myself clearly enough.
[This is how the graph looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmE5P.png)

Sorry if this is too dumb, I'm new to R and don't have much experience with loops, let alone with loops AND graphs. Any ideas on how I could correct this?

**EDIT:** I did as stefan said and used the **.data** like this

```
    for(i in 3:12) {
  GeneName <- colnames(AllPatients[, i])
  FileName <- paste0(GeneName, ".png")
  ggplot(AllPatients, aes(x = TP53, y = .data[[GeneName]])) + 
    geom_point()
  ggsave(FileName)
}
```

and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Try `{{GeneName}}`

Comment: The issue is that `GeneName` is a string. Using the so called `.data` pronoun try `y = .data[[GeneName]]`